# Converting numpy array which elements are numpy arrays to a list of numpy arrays

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, numpy

I have a 4D numpy array which each element is a numpy array itself. I want to convert it to a list of numpy arrays. I saw `tolist()` but it is also converting each element to a list as well.

My numpy array which each element is a numpy array:

[image]

Is there a direct way to create list from above numpy array  which elements are numpy arrays?

Desired List:

[image]

Comment: Can you share a [minimal reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example?

Comment: Added in the question

Comment: That's not a [mcve].  It's a display from some sort of summarizer (spyder's?).  But it appears to me that you have a 4d array with float elements.  Dtype would `object` it is was an array with array elements.  `tolist()` unpacks the array - all the way down.  `list(arr)` will unpack just the outer/first dimension, making a list of 3d arrays.  But why do you need a list?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can transform your 4D array to 1D array thanks to the `flatten()` function like [Here](https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-convert-a-2d-numpy-array-to-a-1d-array-in-python)!. After you can transform it to list